# Visual Studio 2010 project settings for pre-baked MS code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates

I'm not a much of a programmer, but I'm trying to follow this 4 part guide to store Windows logs in SQL:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552512(v=vs.90).aspx

In the first part, they discuss using an "Application Settings File".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552510(v=vs.90).aspx

Is that like an app.config? I tried using the provided XML as an app.config and even generated the .xsd schema. When I do that I receive:

"The name 'Settings' does not exist in the current context"

MS is providing all the code, so I must be throwing it together wrong. If someone could let me know what template to use in Visual Studio, I think I could take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click a project in your solution and select Properties. Then select the Settings tab. It will probably look like this:

[image]

Click the link to create a settings file, which will have its values stored for you in `app.config` - you can use the Visual Studio editor to make settings changes.

[image]

Comment: Thank You! That MS doc doesn't make much sense for the uninitiated.